# Azure Data Factory storage event trigger - authentication

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-eventgrid

How does Azure Data Factory authenticate incoming messages from Event Grid? That is, in this picture, how does the "push message" from Event Grid to Data Factory get authenticated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger#storage-event-trigger-data-factory-pipeline-run

[image]

**What identity is being used when delivering these notifications to the data factory endpoint and how is the authentication happening?**

---

I've tried to figure this out for myself by inspecting the Event Grid Subscription that ADF creates on the storage account, using this AZ CLI command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az_eventgrid_event_subscription_show

`az eventgrid event-subscription show --name "abc123-..." --source-resource-id /subscriptions/subId/resourceGroups/rgName/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageAcctName --include-full-endpoint-url true --include-attrib-secret true`

The full endpointUrl includes the triggerName, querystring parameters that point to the specific factory, resourceGroup, subscription, tenant, etc., but I don't see anything that looks like a token/secret.

It appears to be a "webhook" style endpoint, so I looked up how event grid authenticates to webhooks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#overview. This suggests that it's either AAD Bearer tokens or a client secret as query parameter. Inspecting the event subscription in the portal shows that the AAD option isn't checked and so I assume it is using a secret as query parameter: [image]

Finally, if I try to directly hit the full endpoint url in my browser, data factory appears to request a client certificate for authentication.

Comment: Are you using ADF v2 or managed identity ?

Comment: I'm using ADF v2

Comment: The question is, "how does EVENT GRID authenticate the messages it sends to ADF?"

Comment: Added a picture to clarify the question. What identity is being used in the message Event Grid sends?

Comment: updated answer below

Answer (score -1):

**--Update more clarity**

It is client secret as a query parameter. EventGridTrigger basically sends a HttpTrigger (push) with pre-processed event message for its validation.

- Storage(Event publisher)
- Webhook (Event Handler)
- EventGrid <-> Webhook (subscription)

There is a validation on webhooks, before listening to events, every newly registered webhook need to be validated by event grid first. This is what is implicitly happening when creating subscriptions to events in an event resource like storage account, the arrangement of subscriptions to events is implicit. In case you want to use custom code or on-premise client you will need to respond to validation token the Event Grid will send.

It uses a **validation handshake mechanism** irrespective of the method used (in your case - client secret as a query parameter). As part of creating an Event Subscription, a client secret such as an access token or a shared secret can be used for webhook service to validate.

Event Grid supports two ways of validating the subscription. **Synchronous handshake** and **Asynchronous handshake**

In this case, using Synchronous handshake, Event Grid sends a subscription validation event, whose data portion includes a `validationCode` property. Your application (ADF) verifies that the validation request is for an expected event subscription, and returns the validation code in the response synchronously. Refer: [Validation details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery#validation-details)

When a new event is ready, Event Grid service POSTs an HTTP request to the configured endpoint with the event in the request body.

The point that you see a request for client certificate for authentication when you try to test the endpoint validation and receive events to an HTTP endpoint.

Event Grid uses a Push model that it relays the message as soon as possible when storage drops the message into the system. Event Trigger on Azure Data Factory serves as an active listener to the incoming message and it properly triggers the associated pipeline. Storage Event Trigger itself makes no direct contact with Storage account, Data Factory will make direct contact with Storage, using the credentials stored in the Linked Service. Ensure that Linked Service is set up appropriately

There are two types of managed identity Depending on the method used to create the ADF, the Managed Identity is created automatically whenever an ADF v2 is provisioned. When using SDK/REST API to create ADF, the identity session must be set to true to create MI automatically. If you have the earlier, a managed identity has no client secret. It only has certificates, which you cannot access.

User assigned managed identities enable Azure resources to authenticate to cloud services (e.g. Azure Key Vault) without storing credentials in code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, "what identity is used when event grid delivers the notification to ADF?" It seems like you just copy/pasted snippets from various Microsoft docs, including one that I already linked in my question.

Comment: Yes, so as to refer to the official documentation

Comment: The question you are answering is, "what identity does ADF use to authenticate the calls it makes?" My question is, "what identity is Event Grid using to talk to ADF?"

Comment: Ok, it's a client secret as a query parameter. But for what identity? What identity's client secret is being provided as a query parameter?